# Большой размер  png файла

Tags: android, png

Доброго времени суток. 
Использую для фона png файл, но из размера при попытке его поменять вылетает приложение, решил вместо png использовать gif, но на Alcatel черный фон.
Какие есть альтернативы ?

Comment: размер файла ПНГ, и разрешение картинки в студию!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Альтернативы - не использовать фон одной картинкой. Разбейте экран на логические части и каждую оформляйте. Для больших элементов используйте 9patch. В маленьких можете использовать изображения.
Картинка в фоне будет плохо смотреться в разных разрешениях, либо кушать лишнюю память.

Ну а с gif android вообще не дружит..

Comment: Чтобы посчитать размер загруженной картинки, посмотрите конфигурацию декодирования. Если там 1 пиксель занимает 4 байта(стандарт), то размер в оперативной памяти будет ширина*вышина*4байта. При стандартных ~40мб на процесс это может быть существенным.

Comment: Большое спасибо ─ помогло !

Answer (score 2):

Лучше используйте PNG, но попробуйте его оптимизировать c помощью, например, [tinyPNG](http://highload.com.ua/post/TinyPNG+-+%D0%9E%D0%BD%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD+%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F+PNG).